# For Loop only showing last value, how can I show each one?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Quiz</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>QUICKY QUIZ!</header>
  <section class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center" id="index-btn-grid">
  </section>

  <div class="container"></div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I know for a fact that this questions been asked too many times, but as a new person learning JavaScript, it can get a bit overwhelming I guess you can say. So currently I'm trying to create a Quiz application where both the Questions and Answers change upon hitting "Next". As silly as it sounds, I got the next button to finally work, and I finally managed to make the next question pop up in the box.

I intend on every value of the for loop is ran and each new value is displayed when the"Next" button is displayed. Like so:

Example: 
My Array would be [a,b,c,d]

When I hit "next" after starting with "a", I intend on "b" to pop up, then "c" would pop up after hitting "next" again.

Instead, when I hit "next" after "a", "d" pops up.

I've tried my best and spent quite enough time on reading other threads and "googling" it but right now reading solutions that are pretty "up there" with someone else's code and formatting different is pretty hard to comprehend right now for me being noob.

So below is what I have, please let me know what I can do to achieve my goal. I'd rather not add another drop to the bucket of questions like this but I'd like some help as I'm stumped right now. After I figure the questions out I want to do the buttons with what I learned. I've been on YouTube, MDN, w3 and seen threads on this....Ignore my cluster and I appreciate the time. Thank you guys!

```
let questionEl = document.getElementById('question');

const questions = [
{
  question: 'What color is the White House',
  answers:[

    { text: 'White', correct: true},
    { text: 'Black', correct: false},
    { text: 'Grey', correct: false},
    { text: 'Blue', correct: false},

          ]
},   
{
  question: 'What color is Rainbow?',
  answers:[

    { text: 'All of Them', correct: true},
    { text: 'Apple', correct: false},
    { text: 'Only Brown', correct: false},
    { text: 'Ford Mustang', correct: false},


          ]
},   
{
  question: '9 + 1 =?',
  answers:[

    { text: '10', correct: true},
    { text: '9', correct: false},
    { text: '01', correct: false},
    { text: '91', correct: false},

          ]
},      
];

function showQuestion(){

  let questionEl = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[0].question;
  var answerButtonsEl = document.getElementById("answer0").innerHTML = questions[0].answers[0].text;
  var answerButtonsEl = document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = questions[0].answers[1].text;
  var answerButtonsEl = document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = questions[0].answers[2].text;
  var answerButtonsEl = document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = questions[0].answers[3].text;

};

function nextQuestionSet(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = (questions[i].question); }

};
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you add a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993) with the minimal amount of code possible to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Ya would you happen to have the HTML that goes with this?

Comment: Just posted, sorry about the formatting, this site is so new for me.

Comment: No there is already *far too much* code.  What this question needs is focus, not more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a global variable to count current question when doing next like

```
var count=0;
function nextQuestionSet(){
count++;
if(count<7) { 
 document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = (questions[count].question); 
 document.getElementById("answer0").innerHTML = questions[count].answers[0].text; 
 document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = questions[count].answers[1].text; 
 document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = questions[count].answers[2].text;
 document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = questions[count].answers[3].text; 
}
else{
// you are already on last question 
}
};
```

Comment: This is it, thank you!

I tried doing something like it earlier and I guess I was doing it wrong lol, I see the error now comparing an old version of my code to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like that ?

```js
const questions = 
      [ { question: 'What color is the White House'
        , answers: 
          [ { text: 'White', correct: true  } 
          , { text: 'Black', correct: false } 
          , { text: 'Grey',  correct: false } 
          , { text: 'Blue',  correct: false } 
        ] } 
      , { question: 'What color is Rainbow?'
        , answers: 
          [ { text: 'All of Them',  correct: true  } 
          , { text: 'Apple',        correct: false } 
          , { text: 'Only Brown',   correct: false } 
          , { text: 'Ford Mustang', correct: false } 
        ] } 
      , { question: '9 + 1 =?'
        , answers: 
          [ { text: '10', correct: true  } 
          , { text:  '9', correct: false } 
          , { text: '01', correct: false } 
          , { text: '91', correct: false } 
      ] } ] 

const hmi=
      { question   : document.getElementById('question')
      , Answer     : document.querySelectorAll('#answer-buttons button')
      , No_Question: -1
      , nb_Question: questions.length 
      , responses  : []
      }
const timer=
      { chrono : document.getElementById('chrono')
      , ref    : null
      , delay  : '2m 25s'
      , timeEnd: null
      }
const one_Sec     = 1000
  ,   one_Min     = one_Sec *60
  ,   hmi_score   = document.getElementById('score')
  ,   hmi_Buttons = document.querySelector('#answer-buttons')
  ;
function SetQuestion()
  {
  let isQuestion = (hmi.No_Question < hmi.nb_Question)
  hmi.question.textContent                  = isQuestion ? questions[ hmi.No_Question ].question : 'Quizz ending'
  hmi.Answer.forEach((el,n)=>
    {
    el.value       = n
    el.textContent = isQuestion ? questions[ hmi.No_Question ].answers[n].text : '---'
    })
  }
hmi_Buttons.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return

  if (hmi.No_Question<0)
    { startChrono() }
  else
    { hmi.responses.push({ qNo: hmi.No_Question, resp: parseInt(e.target.value )}) }
  hmi.No_Question++
  SetQuestion()  

  if (hmi.No_Question === hmi.nb_Question)
    { Quizending()  }
  }
function startChrono()
  {
  timer.chrono.textContent =  timer.delay

  timer.timeEnd = new Date().getTime() + get_MS( timer.delay )

  timer.ref = setInterval(_=>
    {
    let now = new Date().getTime()
      , tim = timer.timeEnd - now
      ;
    if ( tim<=0 )
      {
      tim=0
      Quizending()
      }
    timer.chrono.textContent = ` ${Math.floor(tim/one_Min)}m ${Math.floor((tim % one_Min )/one_Sec)}s`   
    }
    ,one_Sec);
  }
function Quizending()
  {
  clearInterval(timer.ref) 
  hmi.No_Question = hmi.nb_Question
  SetQuestion()  

  // score...
  let Points = hmi.responses.reduce((a,c)=>a+=questions[c.qNo].answers[c.resp].correct ? 1:0,0)

  hmi_score.textContent = `Score = ${Points} / ${hmi.nb_Question}` 

  // console.log( JSON.stringify(hmi.responses,0,2) )
  }

// converse delay string 'Xm Ys' to milliseconds
function get_MS (timer_val)
  {
  let vDelay = { m:0, s:0 }
    , vNum   = '0'
    , ret    = { add: 0, dis: ''}
  for (const c of timer_val)
    {
    if (/[0-9]/.test(c) )
      { vNum += c }
    if (/[ms]/.test(c) )
      {
      vDelay[c] = parseInt(vNum)
      vNum      = '0'
    } }
  return (vDelay.m*one_Min)+(vDelay.s*one_Sec)
  }
```

```css
#answer-buttons button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 20em;
  margin: .4em;
}
```

```html
<h5 id="chrono">?</h5>
<h4 id="question">Quizz</h4>
<h5 id="score"></h5>
<div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
  <button class="btn"> click any button to start ! </button>
  <button class="btn"> click any button to start ! </button>
  <button class="btn"> click any button to start ! </button>
  <button class="btn"> click any button to start ! </button>
</div>
```

*I like chronos code, (get_MS is from*  [Modify countdown script to allow for multiple countdowns per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294674/modify-countdown-script-to-allow-for-multiple-countdowns-per-page/58477464#58477464) *)*

Comment: @javyb92 In this case, it would be nice to validate my answer, isn't it?